# Why are ASCII control characters ignored when using Ctrl+Shift+U?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, input, unicode, special-characters

I'm trying to enter a tab character in Firefox/Chrome text boxes without having to copy-paste from Emacs. The combination Ctrl+Shift+U then `0009` does not work. In fact, it does not seem to work for most "control" characters. However, it works for pretty much any *printable* character including non-ASCII. This is really bizarre. Google doesn't seem to reveal any such inconsistent behavior. Anyone know why this combination bans whitespace? I can repeat this behavior in any program including Leafpad and LibreOffice.

`U+2023`: ‣
`U+0100`: Ā
`U+0009`: (nothing)
`U+000A`: (nothing)
`U+0020`: (space)

Comment: Not that it helps particularily, but the problem is tied to your configuration, i.e. that's not something supposed to happen (I can insert all of those). I wouldn't know that to suggest though.

Comment: Thanks @kos. I actually made a breakthrough. I can type the tab character via that shortcut only as root! Not sure what's going on yet but I will keep investigating.

Answer (score 2):

Got it. The reason it was working as root and not my regular user was because the environment variables `GTK_IM_MODULE` and `QT_IM_MODULE` were being forced to `xim` for all regular users, regardless of runs of `im-config`. The only module I have installed under Lubuntu is `ibus`, so I'm not surprised by this strange behavior. A few articles on the net brought those variables to my attention so I started debugging around them. When I noticed they were being set to `xim` persistently, I decided to force them to `ibus` under `/etc/environment`. You have the less aggressive option of setting them in `.bashrc` or some equivalent. Regardless, this will restore full Ctrl+Shift+U functionality.

Comment: thank you! in my Linux Mint I was able to modify the input method from a GUI app (search for Input) and set it to `none` (instead of xim). To have it work I had to restart the X session (maybe that's why your im-config was ignored?).