# Gnome ctrl-shift-u fails for a handful of unicode code points

Tags: encoding, compose-key, unicode-entry

Pressing ctrl-shift-u followed by some hexadecimal digits types a unicode character with the given code-point, for instance ctrl-shift-u 2266 gives `≦`.  Strangely, some unicode code points fail in my configuration (mostly fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04), for instance typing ctrl-shift-u 2264 inserts nothing (instead of `≤`), in the same way that pressing the compose key and some inexistent combination inserts nothing.

Testing all numbers starting at 2200, I found that the following fail: 2219 (`∙`) 221a (`√`) 2248 (`≈`) 2264 (`≤`) 2265 (`≥`) 2320 (`⌠`) 2321 (`⌡`) 2580 (`▀`) 2584 (`▄`) 2588 (`█`) 258c (`▌`) 2590 (`▐`) 2591 (`░`) 2592 (`▒`) 2593 (`▓`) 25a0 (`■`).  Actually, I found the first handful by accident, then came across the [KOI8-R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-R) encoding, which seems to contain precisely these characters that do not work for me.  There is nothing Russian about my install (bought the computer new, in France, and I have not selected Russian locale or anything like that).

While I don't routinely type such characters directly using ctrl-shift-u, they also fail with the compose key, specifically typing Compose `>` `=` inserts nothing instead of `≥`.

Answer (score 0):

I had in my `.profile` a left-over setting (brought forward from a previous computer) `export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"`.  I resolved the issue by changing the setting to `export GTK_IM_MODULE="ibus"`, as suggested in [Why are ASCII control characters ignored when using Ctrl+Shift+U?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685931/why-are-ascii-control-characters-ignored-when-using-ctrlshiftu)

There remains the mystery of why this particular list of code-points (KOI8-R) failed.